# Issue with directory ownership when mounting usb hdd

Tags: mount, hard-disk, raspbian

I am hoping someone might be able to help explain an issue I have with regards to directory permissions I am getting when trying to mount 2 external USB HDDs.  For reference this is on Raspbian but I believe this to be a general linux/debian question.

First off I have created two mount points under /media/

```
pi@mypi:/media $ ls -l
total 8
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root 4096 Jun 29 12:38 hdd
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root 4096 Jun 29 12:37 hdd2
```

I then identified the UUID of the two disks I wanted to mount:

```
pi@mypi:/media $ sudo lsblk -f
NAME        FSTYPE LABEL       UUID                             MOUNTPOINT
sda         ext4   HomeBackup  2e3ece57-6526-4acd-aba3-79f0937ecad0
sde
└─sde1      ext4   HomeBackup2 f54dad28-04a8-4bad-9d84-38571b2e2155
```

Which I then used to update my `/etc/fstab` file:

```
pi@mypi:/media $ cat /etc/fstab
...
UUID=2e3ece57-6526-4acd-aba3-79f0937ecad0 /media/hdd ext4 noatime,nofail,defaults 0 0
UUID=f54dad28-04a8-4bad-9d84-38571b2e2155 /media/hdd2 ext4 noatime,nofail,defaults 0 0
```

However when I then mount the drives one of them is changed owner ship to my user `pi` whilst the other one remains as owned by `root` which makes no sense to me as the setup is identical for both of them..

```
pi@mypi:/media $ sudo mount -a
pi@mypi:/media $ ls -l
total 8
drwxrwxr-x 10 pi   pi   4096 Jun 29 13:45 hdd
drwxr-xr-x  3 root root 4096 Jun 29 12:29 hdd2
```

Please can someone help point out what I've missed here ?

Comment: Do the 2 folders /media/hdd and /media/hdd2 exist before boot-up?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you mount a file system, the mount point assumes the ownership and permissions of the root directory of the mounted file system. What you’re seeing indicates that `/dev/sda`’s root directory is owned by `pi:pi` (or rather, its uid and gid match `pi`’s on your system), while `/dev/sde1`’s is owned by root.

`chown` will fix things for you if necessary.